# Dygraph x-axis not displaying first date

Tags: dygraphs

I want to show the first date in x-axis always when the graph in unzoomed state. Below code skips the first date in x-axis while plotting in graph.

Please find the below code snippet,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
        `X,Y,Z
        2012/03/13,-4,3
        2012/03/14,-2,3
        2012/03/15,0,3
        2012/03/16,2,6
        2012/03/17,4,8
        2012/03/18,6,9
        2012/03/19,8,9
        2012/03/20,10,8
        2012/03/21,12,6
        2012/03/22,14,3`,
        {
            legend: 'always',
            xRangePad: 20
        });
})
```